# SQL Join one to many extract value from group of same key value where condition is met

Tags: sql, join, one-to-many, netezza

I have two tables with a one to many relationship i'm trying to join. The parent table has a unique key value shared with the child table. The child table keeps history for that key so there is multiple records. Example below.

What I need is to extract the worker name for an alert id where the action is 'Alert Closed' for a given group of the same alert id. If that group of same alert id doesn't have a record with action = 'Alert Closed' than take the worker name with the most recent timestamp. I'm lacking the knowledge on how to compare timestamp columns also I get duplicates still when 'Alert Closed' is true.

Table 1

```
alert_id            
---------
123         
456         
537
```

Table 2

```
alert_id    worker_name action          timestamp
---------------------------------------------------------
123         system      Alert Created   8/6/2016  8:05:26 
123         james bond  Alert Opened    8/6/2016  8:05:30
123         james bond  Alert Closed    8/6/2016  8:05:35
123         james bond  Record updated  8/6/2016  8:05:35
456         system      Alert Created   8/6/2016  8:05:26
456         admin       Alert updated   8/6/2016  8:06:14
537         system      alert created   8/6/2016  8:07:20
537         Mary hill   Alert Closed    8/6/2016  8:08:26
```

Resulting table should be:

```
alert_id    worker_name     
-----------------------
123         james bond      
456         admin       
537         Mary Hill
```

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: is this Sql Server or MySql etc?

Comment: netezza udb if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  You can approach it using `row_number()`.  The trick is to get the ordering right:

```
select t2.*
from (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by alert_id
                                order by (case when action = 'Alert Closed' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         timestamp desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: then i would just left outer join this with table one right since all i need from table two is the employee name.